# I am trying to insatall PHP Composer in Mac OS 10.13.6 and facing a problem

Tags: php, composer-php

i am trying to install PHP Composer in my Mac os 10.13.6 with terminal . But when i run that command => mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer it does not compile and gives me this message => mv: rename composer.phar to /usr/local/bin/composer: Permission denied.
Can somebody help me where am i wrong to install PHP composer ?

You can see the screenshot

[image: 1]

Thanks

Comment: Your user probably just doesn't have the permission to write to the `/usr/local/bin` folder.

Comment: Which parts of that error message are unclear to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions. You should run `mv` as root if you want to move `composer` to `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: how to run mv as a root ?

Comment: Use `su` or `sudo -s` - depending on how is your system set up. Or do `sudo mv ...` if your system uses `sudo`.